# iphone MKMapView 34000 annotation

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift

Hello everyone I would like to kindly advice on the strategy to be used.
I have a database with 34,000 points of interest to be included as an annotation in the MapKit.
now I decided to create a webservice that returns a json for these elimenti.
My problem is that I can not put 34,000 points of interest otherwise my application would become very slow.
I would ask if anyone had the same problem. Which strategy to use?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to achieve this. 
 1. Add only those annotations which can be viewed on the screen and add annotations dynamically when user scrolls on the map.
 2. Now the second case what if user zooms out of the mapview. In that case you can create clusters instead of annotations for each point indicating the number of annotations under the cluster.

I guess this tutorial might help you a little bit.

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-handle-large-amounts-of-data-on-maps